# Подключить БД (MySQL) к Steam API

Tags: php, mysql, sql, steam-web-api

Разбираю Steam API, скачал демку. Получить данные — без проблем.

[SteamAuthentication](https://github.com/SmItH197/SteamAuthentication) (вход на сайт с сессиями и cookie, без внесения данных в БД). Скачал.

Подскажите, пожалуйста, куда лепить SQL-запрос, чтобы вносило данные в БД?

Comment: Чем вы пользуетесь? Денвер? Или что-то другое?

Answer (score 2):

На индексной странице пишем

```
session_start();
isset($_Session['steamid']){
```

Дальше пишем проверку есть ли такой пользователь в базе данных, если нету то создаем такого пользователя и присваиваем ему данные которые были получены от скрипта авторизации. Если пользователь есть, делаем то что нужно.